# Remove one single word before a delimiter using sed

Tags: sed

How should I remove a single word before a delimiter using `sed`

For e.g. if the input is `hello I am eating: mango` and delimiter is `:` the output should be `hello I am : mango`

Comment: Wouldn't `sed 's/[a-z]+:/:/g' file` do it for you? P.S use `sed -E` if mac

Comment: @ComputerFellow no it won't. by default sed applies BRE, your `+` is a literal `plus` sign, it matches nothing in OP's example.  also, if the word had `[A-Z]`, it will fail too.

Comment: Works with the  `-E` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kent$  sed 's/[^:[:space:]]*:/:/' <<<"hello I am eating: mango"
hello I am : mango
```

The sed one-liner, changes the first `foo:` into `:`

Comment: There is one problem to it: for input string `sed 's/[^:[:space:]]*:/:/' <<"eating:"` returns empty string. However if there is no space, the string should remain as is. Please can you help with this.

Comment: it is a new requirement... I will think about it when I got time.